# What is an algorithm for finding the shortest path in a graph that crosses each edge at least once.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I am looking for an algorithm that, given a graph, finds the shortest (or approximately shortest) path that crosses all edges at least onces. (Multiple times crossing an edge is allowed!)

The graph is connected and undirected. All edges have a weight of 1.

Unfortunately I do not have much background in graph theory. I need the algorithm for a line following robot. The robot drives on a field like this image: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723002546/https://www.nctm.org/mathforum/)
The robot can move on the black lines. However some edges are blocked. I need an algorithm to find a route that determines a path that crosses all the non-blocked edges at least once. (It has to find a certain object placed on one of the edges.) I modeling the grid as a graph. The nodes are the intersections of the black lines. The edges are the black lines between them.

I have been searching for algorithms that - given a graph - finds a route going through all the edges (an Eulerian path). However I couldn't find an algorithm that allows multiple times crossing an edge. This is necesarry because there are notes having an even number of edges.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want an *efficient* algorithm? Surely you could enumerate all paths in the graph and then sort by length. ;)

Comment: How can a path "cross" an edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359078/minimal-path-all-edges-at-least-once

Comment: @Neal Thank for your response. It has to be reasonable efficient. It has to be solved by a computer script (in C) in a few seconds with a graph of 25 nodes, each having 4 edges at max.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, it is similar indeed. The difference is that the end location doesn't matter, as long as it passes each edge.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, it is similar indeed. The difference is that the end location doesn't matter, as long as it passes each edge.

Comment: To turn a CPP-cycle finding algorithm into a path finding algorithm:  For each pair of vertices add a bogus vertex with one edge to each member of the pair.  A cycle in this augmented graph is a path in the unaugmented graph.  Since, for 25 vertices, there are only 300 augmented graphs to check, this shouldn't break your time budget.